# Проверка является ли введённые символы восьмеричным числом?

Tags: c++

В задаче говорится: проверить является ли введённые символы восьмеричным числом?
Написал нижеследующий код, но почему то `flag == false` даже при истинности значения. Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char c;
    bool flag = true;

    do{
        cin >>c;
        if(!isdigit(c) || c > 7)
              flag = false;

    }while (!c);

   cout << (flag ? "YES" : "NO");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `7` это число, а символ это `'7'`.

Comment: Из вашей постановки задачи не ясно, какой именно формат записи восьмеричного числа является допустимым (знак допускается или нет?). Тем не менее, вместо "изобретения велосипеда" можно было прочитать строку и затем воспользоваться стандартной функцией `std::strtol` или `std::stoi` с основанием `8`, и она бы почти все проверила за вас.

Comment: Именно так и ставится задачи без уточнения отрицательные или нет. "На вход программы поступает символьная строка (длина строки не больше 300 символов)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вам уже сказали, `c > 7` сравнивет  с семеркой код числа, а не число. Если пользователь пользователь ввел, скажем, `5`, то сравненеие получится `53 > 7`. [image]

В ASCII таблице все цифры идут по порядку. Поэтому чтобы преобразовать код цифры в 
цифру, надо сделать `c - '0'`. '5' - '0' = 53 - 48 = 5

```
if(!isdigit(c) || (c - '0') > 7)
```

Comment: `(c - '0') > 7` это какая-то перверсия, можно же сразу сравнить с символом `('7' < c)` или даже без `isdigit`: `if((c < '0') or ('7' < c))`

Comment: Или несколько лаконичнее: `c > '7'`

Comment: `isdigit(c)` дает неопределенное поведение, если `c` отрицательное (и `!= EOF`). Правильно вот так: `isdigit((unsigned char)c)`. Пруф: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

Comment: Скорее всего отрицательных символов не будет, но так как в условии это не уточнено, то видимо надо использовать  isdigit((unsigned char)c) и функцию atoi() .

Answer (score 1):

`c > 7` сравнивает символ (в диапазоне `'0'`...`'9'` в этом контексте) с числом. код символа `'0'` - 48, соответственно результат будет всегда true. Соответственно проверку можно написать проще

```
if((c < '0') or ('7' < c))
```

Answer (score 1):

еще вариант...

```
flag = (int(c - '0') >> 3) ? false : true
```